# Tasypie serialize to plist

Tags: django, plist, tastypie

Does anyone can help about to serialize my tastypie api to response with plist format messages?

Tastypie documentation has a link that doesn't work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To serialize  to plist you need to install biplist (pip install biplist). After installing it you can get plist format just by specifying format in url /?format=plist.